# How do I write a macro in WoW to yell one of 2 statements?

Tags: automation, lua, world-of-warcraft

I want to write a wow macro that has the character say one of 2 statements and I want to be able to choose which statement. I'm fine with either having a sequence (alternates between each message), having the game detect if the player has a buff or not, or having the game detect if a modifier key (such as `alt, shift, ctrl`) is being held. If I wanted to create a macro for a spell, I would just use

```
/cast [mod] spell1
/cast [nomod] spell2
```

but this does not work with a `/s` command (I've tried). I've tried diving into basic Lua code, but have not been able to make it work. Here's what I have tried using a Lua if then else command that tests to see if the player has a buff or not (I used "Travel Form" as a placeholder buff on my druid)

```
/run if (UnitAura("player", "Travel Form")) 
        then SendChatMessage("Statement1","say") 
        else SendChatMessage("Statement2","say") 
        end
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

Here are two examples with using modifier keys. They are a bit condensed because I like my macros short.

- https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/API_IsModifierKeyDown

```lua
/run SendChatMessage(IsModifierKeyDown() and "Statement1" or "Statement2")
```

- https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/API_SecureCmdOptionParse

```lua
/run SendChatMessage(SecureCmdOptionParse("[mod] Statement1; Statement2"))
```

As for checking if you have e.g. a buff (by name), you need to iterate the indices for `UnitAura()` or use [GetPlayerAuraBySpellID](https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/API_GetPlayerAuraBySpellID) (less compact example)

```lua
/run if GetPlayerAuraBySpellID(783) then SendChatMessage("Statement1") else SendChatMessage("Statement2") end
```